# The Cucumber Paradox

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

Suppose you have 100 lbs of cucumbers and these cucumbers consist of 99% water. You decide to leave the cucumbers in the sun for a while until they consist of 98% water. You bring the cucumbers back in, and you think, "Now the cucumbers should weigh a little less than they were before, right?" But, you try as hard as you can, and you still can't figure out how much they weight. **How much do the cucumbers weigh?** Good Luck!

*This is a straight mathematical/logical puzzle, but be warned: it isn't very straightforward. :)*

**EDIT**: When I say a percentage like 99% I meant 99 percent of weight is water. Sorry about the ambiguous question :)

**EDIT #2**: Apparently, the fact that 100lbs came out of nowhere is confusing, so I'm creating a back-up story...*you are delivered 100 lbs of cucumbers that you bought on Amazon...because you did not use Amazon Prime, they dried up (shipping took a very long time), and some water disappeared (described above). What is the weight of the cucumbers now? (Please do not flag for "trying to promote something" because I lowkey do not work for Amazon.) XD*

Comment: This puzzle works very well because the numbers are also so close to one other - 100 lbs, 99% and 98%, which hides a much larger difference in that 1 percentage point. In that sense, it is reminiscent of the other puzzle of the missing dollar.

Comment: @Phylyp Spoiler alert.

Comment: -1: This question requires an assumption about what you mean by "percent".

Comment: 99% V/V or W/W? meaning as weight or as volume?

Comment: I'm not following the part about not being able to figure out how much they weigh.  You weighed them originally by some means and determined that they weighed 100 lbs.  Why can't you use the same means to determine how much they weight now?

Comment: An extremely old and well-known puzzle.

Comment: @Michael, because when the answer is given there is no 'riddle'.

Comment: @Geliormth Ah ok, I guess it's just sub-optimal wording then...

Comment: Is this even a riddle? Can just write it as a simple system of equations and [drop in wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B+t1%3D100,+l1%3D(99%2F100)t1,+s1%3Dt1-l1,+l2%3D(98%2F100)t2,+t2+%3D+l2+%2B+s1%7D) to solve...

Comment: @Guest - If you enjoy doing things the really hard way and also pulling out sledge hammers to kill flies, then yes, you can solve it that way. Also, a puzzle is not about being hard to figure out. Instead, it is about being tricky to figure out .In this case, pretty much everyone upon first hearing it will immediately think the answer should be about 99 lbs. The trick to this puzzle is to recognize that this obvious idea is horribly wrong.

Comment: I'm removing the lateral-thinking tag. Your disclaimer about why it's there notwithstanding, it's encouraging inappropriately lateral-thinking answers, and it's not really needed anyway - an unintuitive solution that nonetheless follows directly from correctly applying math isn't "lateral-thinking" at all.

Comment: @NL628 thanks for the edit. Might not make a differnece for everyone but when I first read I immediately thought "I could do this if I knew if it was 99% by weight and not volume"

Comment: Can you help me understand why the title refers to this as a "paradox"?  What are the apparently contradictory facts?

Comment: @Michael: technically the problem doesn't say that you weighed the cucumbers to determine that they are 100 pounds.  Perhaps you were told. Or even if you did weigh them, maybe the scale was on the truck that delivered the cucumbers and it's gone now. Or the truck ran into it when leaving and broke it. Maybe you have a somewhat unhelpful scale that only says whether something is less than/equal to/more than 100 pounds but doesn't say by how much. Maybe you just like solving problems using logic or math.There are any number of reasons why you might not be able to weigh the cucumbers.

Comment: I knew this one as the "martian potatoes paradox" and by searching a little bit, I just found out that Wikipedia knew it too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato_paradox

Comment: @PaulSinclair, it's not "really hard" to drop all the constraints into some algebra solver; neither is it "tricky." There is also nothing to "figure out." It's the equivalent of being given a list of numbers and dropping them in OEIS. The example I gave shows it can be done mechanically, without any thought at all. If it looks less "very hard" to you, make a few inferences and use `{a=(98/100)b, b=a+1}` instead (it should work with any mom-and-pop solver).

Comment: @Guest - "1% of 100 lbs is 1 lb. 1 lb is 2% of 50 lbs" is much easier than even figuring out your first set of equations, much less entering the equations in some solver.

Comment: @PaulSinclair,  the fact that an intuitive solution exists doesn't change the fact that you can simply drop the constraints in a solver and out pops your answer. There shouldn't be anything to "figure out" about those equations; they're just the information from the question in the same order it's presented there. There's also nothing hard about entering them in a solver. That's like saying "puzzles" about identifying number sequences you can look up on OEIS are fine because you personally can't figure out how to enter the numbers into the OEIS search tool, but you intuitively recognize them.

Comment: @Guest - there is nothing "intuitive" about that calculation. It is a direct application of the definitions. And the comment was simply to explain why I called your method the really hard way. It is like the guy who has to pull out a calculator to figure out what 2 + 3 is. I addressed your misunderstanding of the nature of puzzles in my original comment.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, clearly we have different ideas about what a puzzle is. To me this is a straight textbook math problem. This is evidenced by the fact that it can be solved by punching it into a calculator, without thinking about it. I have a Kordemsky book with some math puzzles in it. None of them look remotely like this; they all require some *thought*, not just pure mechanical calculation. Those, I'm convinced, are puzzles. This is not. From my perspective, *you* have misunderstood the nature of puzzles.

Comment: @Guest I do not want to try and defend my problem
but I believe that I enjoyed solving this problem and I would like
to share it with all of you guys on Puzzling SE. Please, for the sake of
this problem, do not argue here in the comments. Thank you guys so much for your help!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I'm gonna say:

> 50 lbs

Explanation:

> (Assuming the 99% water is by weight)
>
>  - The `% of X` in the cucumbers is calculated as `Weight of X` / `Weight of the cucumbers`.
>
>  - In the start there's `99% water` and `1% solids` in 100 lbs of cucumbers.
>
>  - Only the `Weight of water` will change in the process. The `Weight of solids` *won't change* after evaporation.
>
>  - Going from 99% water to 98% water means the `% of solids` *doubled* from 1% to 2%.
>
>  - Recall that `% of solids` = `Weight of solids` / `Weight of cucumbers`.
>
>  - Since the `% of solids` was *doubled*, and `Weight of solids` *didn't change*, that could only mean the `Weight of cucumbers` is *halved*.
>
>  As such, the remaining total weight is 100 / 2 = **50 lbs**.

Comment: Too fast again :)

Comment: You won't mind if I wait for more responses before accepting, do you?

Comment: No problem with that c: considering you included lateral-thinking i'd love to see what others come up with as well!

Comment: Nice... 33 upvotes :) You finally get the green checkmark!!!

Comment: Ah yes, the power of being featured on hot network questions. That was a nice surprise to wake up to xD

Comment: In all seriousness this was a nice puzzle though. Not too hard, simple enough to be understood/attempted/solved/explained without needing any papers to take note of stuff, the numbers are deviously designed to be intuitively misleading, and the solution gives that 'gotcha, that's brilliant' feel. It's a fantastic light riddle to tell verbally! Definitely one i'll keep in mind in case i can use it during conversations :)

Answer (score 30):

By basic algebra,

> 100 lb has 1% solids, i.e. 1 lb. The final state has the same amount of solids, plus the remaining water. We'll call the weight of the remaining water $x$. So $$\text{dried weight} = x + 1 $$
>  This water $x$ is now 98% of the weight, i.e. $$ \frac{98}{100} = \frac{x}{x+1} $$
>  $$ 98x + 98 = 100x $$
>  $$ 98 = 2x $$
>  $$ x = 49 $$
>  So $$ \text{total weight} = x+1 = 50 \text{ lb.} $$

I hope that was not too roundabout.

By intuitive logic,

> 1 pound of solids was 1%, but is now 2% of the total mass. 
>
> So if 2% of something is one pound, how much is 100% of that something? 
>
> 50 times 2% makes 100%, so it must be 50 x 1lb = 50lb.

Comment: Having added some math formatting to your post, might I encourage you to include your units on those numbers throughout all the equations? =)

Comment: Good Job. This is the correct answer, (although sadly not the first). Amazing job with the LaTeX. Congratulations!

Answer (score 13):

Given:

> - 100 lbs. initial cucumber weight, 99% is water
>  - Only water removed resulting in water becoming 98% of final cucumber weight

Therefore:

> - Initial weight of 'not water' is 1% of initial cucumber weight (100%-99%)
>  - Weight of 'not water' is 1% of initial 100 lbs. = 1 lb.
>  - The 1 lb. weight of 'not water' is 2% of final cucumber weight (100%-98%)
>  - 1 lb is 2% of **50 lbs.** (1 lb/.02), your final cucumber weight!

Comment: Hey, welcome to puzzling.stackexchange.com! Have you noticed these spoiler blocks in other's answers? You should be doing them to. Click `edit` on one of the answer to see how spoilers are done if you are not sure how to add them!

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was just trying to figure that out!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour]!**)  How does your answer add to the identical ones already given? You should always look at existing answers before providing one of your own, to ensure you are not just adding a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Rubio.  My answer may provide a simpler solution.  Also, my reasons for posting was not just to solve the problem but also to play with the puzzling.stackexchange.com formatting since I've not posted here before.  Pardon the intrusion!

Answer (score 4):

I mean, it is tagged lateral thinking...

> You had 100 lbs of cucumber plants and watered them so that they were 99% water. Then you left them in the sun to grow, and the cucumbers grew. They are only 98% water because the mass of the plants is included.

So the weight?

> I’ll calculate this part when I have time. How many cucumbers does 100 lbs of plants produce?

Comment: It was also stated pretty clearly that it's a straight mathematical/logical puzzle, but labelled lateral-thinking *only* because it isn't very straightforward. Don't use it as an excuse for wild flights of fancy.  (The lateral-thinking tag was inappropriate to begin with and is now removed.)

Comment: I've gotta give it to you. Entirely my fault for giving the lateral-thinking tag. I looked up its definition and took it too seriously. +1 lol

Answer (score -2):

> (100 lbs)(453.592 g/lbs) = 45359.2 g

Pound to gram conversion

> (45359.2 g)/(.99 g/cm^3) = 4581.374 cm^3

Density of water @ 30 C (or 86 F) for scenario's sake, so a warm day

density = mass/volume

> disregard sig figs btw: 
>  (4581.374 cm^3)(98%/99%) = 4535.572 cm^3

Cucumbers shrink when the water evaporates

> (4535.572 cm^3)(.99 g/cm^3) = 44901.026 g

Conversion to lbs:

> (44901.026 g)/(453.592 g/lbs) = 98.9899 lbs

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Could you edit your answer to include spoiler tags, so as not to spoil the solution for anyone who wants to try the puzzle for themselves?

Comment: @F1Krazy - not a problem for this answer, because even under the assumption that the percentages were by volume instead of weight, this calculation is wrong. It reduces the amount everything by (99/98)%, not just the water.

Answer (score -2):

Using lateral thinking (and building on the @thecoder16's solution)

> They still weigh 100lbs

Reasoning:

> You watered them and they grew. Now they have 2lbs of solids. If they contain 98 lbs of water that will be 98lbs/(2+98)lbs = 98% water.

Although, actually we don't know how much solid remains. Of course, with reasoning like this, there is an infinite number of solutions because:

> You can assume they grew to have N lbs of solids. Now, to calculate their weight you use the algebraic formula: `x / x+n = 0.98` where `n` is the new weight of the solids and `x + n` is their new total weight.

And if we *do* assume that the solids don't change then:

> `x / x+1` solved for x is: 49, and x+1 = 50 lbs

Comment: (See comment on @thecoder16's solution)

Comment: @Rubio, that doesn't change the fact that there are an infinite number of solutions if the weight of the solids are allowed to change. Nothing in the question said they weren't. This solution also covers the case where `N = 1lb` and `X = 49lbs` leading to the accepted answer of 50lbs.

Comment: It doesn't say they aren't sea cucumbers, nor paper cut-outs of cucumbers. It doesn't say they aren't the cucumber shaped projections into our dimension of some extra-dimensional creatures that can change their mass and density at will. It **does** say it's a straight math/logic puzzle.  It's not reasonable to invent facts not in evidence that are required to make a "solution" work, and use the excuse that the problem definition didn't exclude that possibility; why folks are asserting that these are growing cucumber plants, rather than just cucumbers as the plain text says, is beyond me.

Comment: @Rubio they don't have to be growing they could also be rotting/shrinking. My solution still stands as being more complete because it does not *assume* anything about the weight of the solid part of the cucumber. A solution that makes an unstated assumption cannot be complete. I recognized the puzzle immediately, but that's irrelevant, it does not mean that the commonly regarded *correct* answer is the only one. In a puzzle that states that the solids do not change, it would be.

Comment: @Rubio, and besides, none of your silly assumptions change the answer at all.

Comment: @Octopus that was kind of rude. Rubio is only trying to help (plus being an experienced Puzzles.SE user). I don't think the comments were "silly", nor do I agree you should've responded that way.

Comment: @Octopus `My solution still stands as being more complete because it does not assume anything about the weight of the solid part of the cucumber` - I agree that unfounded assumptions weaken an answer, but that's the issue Rubio's taking with yours. I mean, you literally say `You can assume they grew to have N lbs of solids.` How could you argue you didn't make an assumption about the solid weight? The accepted answer here used only the information given to them; that is why it is accepted. You've injected your own information, and so you've solved a different question.

Answer (score -2):

101 lbs

Cucumbers are alive, and they were growing... gain one pound of mass to the same 99 of water and you get 99/101 = 98%

Comment: @Glorfindel Only because Rubio removed that tag at about the same time this answer was posted.  For approximately 95% of this puzzle's lifetime (as of right now), it *was* tagged [lateral-thinking].

Comment: @TrevorPowell Right, thanks. That isn't really apparent from the LQP review queue :)

Answer (score -2):

Sigh - It's NOT SO SIMPLE.  Here's my correction ...

> The dry weight of the cukes is 1 lb.
>  If they are 98% water and 2% dry cuke, then geez 1 lb is 2% of 50lbs.
>  THAT'S surprising!

Comment: You were warned "it isn't very straightforward".

Comment: Akk! You're right - correction to my answer...

Comment: ... making it now redundant with multiple other answers.  (Maybe just delete and hope for better luck next time)